# Combining Logical operator with membership operator in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to combine the Logical operator 'and' with membership operator 'not in' properly. here, I want a clean list with no empty strings and the ones having only punctuation marks.

```
val_list = [['infertility fear', 'teenage pregnancy', 'public health', 'health science', 'parenthood'], ['mass health checkups', 'personality traits', '-', '']]
```

Expected output

```
['infertility fear', 'teenage pregnancy', 'public health', 'health science', 'parenthood', 'mass health checkups', 'personality traits']
```

---

```
flat_val_list = [item.strip() for sublist in val_list for item in sublist if (item != '') and not in (list(string.punctuation))]
```

Error

```
File "<ipython-input-40-3f1a39d4169d>", line 11
    flat_val_list = [item.strip() for sublist in val_list for item in sublist if (item != '') and not in (list(string.punctuation))]
                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `and item not in ...`…!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say `item not in ...`. Here:

```py
flat_val_list = [item.strip() for sublist in val_list for item in sublist if (item != '') and item not in (list(string.punctuation))]
```